# Question was deleted -- why

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-questions

Why was this question deleted?  There was a reasonable question which I answered.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062425/why-do-i-sometimes-get-ambiguous-column-name-errors-when-i-am-not-doing-joins/14071309#14071309

Comment: I think that might be related to the [edit war](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14062425/revisions) and/or the OP's account deletion.

Comment: Looks like the user got nuked, question deletion was just "collateral damage".

Comment: Ah, so the user "left" right as I was answering his/her question.  To bad.  It is a shame we can't be nicer to new users who are slightly frustrated.  This user actually did the right thing and posted a screen shot.

Comment: @Mat - I believe the user deleted their own account -- they made a comment they were going to, but I don't see it now.

Comment: @Hogan: hadn't considered that (I though user deletions took a bit more time than that usually. Might depend on the amount of content I guess).

Comment: Typical case of rage quit.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assumption: The community user automatically deleted the question when the OP user deleted their own account and requested all their content be deleted.

I believe this question is an example of how SO is failing to deliver good content to new users.  This user was dealt with <strike>unusually</strike> harshly and was trying (reasonably) to do the right thing.  Words were exchanged (which always a bad thing) and ultimately a reasonable question was removed from the site.

Comment: That is a pretty sweeping generalisation. In this specific case, I can see that the user was treated poorly by some, who were reprimanded by the majority. The majority of users then also tried to placate the user and defuse the situation. Additionally, while this is an unfortunate circumstance, it is not the norm. The statement "`SO is failing to deliver good content to new users`" doesn't really ring true to me.

Comment: Unusually harshly? I only see *one* comment from *one* person that was unfriendly.

Comment: I would say it really can be considered to be "unusual" that new users get such treatment. And here, there were a couple other users who were quick to try to smooth things over and chastized the 'at fault' party. But the OP also got a bit out of hand.\

Comment: @Asad - Maybe I'm seeing a sub-set of SO since I'm only looking at questions nominated for closure.

Comment: @Hogan Ahhh, yes; that would *definitely* have a negative impact on the overall leaning of the things you see. That was a *great* catch with the syntax for that question, though! It was hard to see in the screenie, and the OP didn't mention it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Thanks.  Maybe I should not look at the closed list -- this is the 2nd question which I've been able to answer and have the question closed right after.  (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058970/dictionarytkey-tvalue-override-indexer-and-findentry#14058970)

Comment: @Hogan That is very unlucky.